# $scope variable undefined even after assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function in one of my Angular controllers and I'm having an issue with it.

At the beginning of the function I try to check if a departure time as been provided, if one hasn't been provided, I assign the current time to it in a HH:mm:ss format.

However, when i try to check the value of $scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime even after assignment, it is still undefined. Why?

```
$scope.search = function () {
    if (!$scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime) {
        var time = new Date();

        var departureTime =
            ("0" + time.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
            ("0" + time.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
            ("0" + time.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

        //12:32:15 app.js:80
        console.log(departureTime);

        $scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime =
            departureTime;
        //undefined app.js:85
        console.log($scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime);
    }

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/train-times/journey?departureStation='
        + $scope.selectedDepartureStation.stationName
        + '&destinationStation='
        + $scope.selectedDestinationStation.stationName
        + '&queryTime='
        + $scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime,
        data: {}
    }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.journeyResult = result;
    });

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/train-times/departure-times?departureStation='
        + $scope.selectedDepartureStation.stationName
        + '&queryTime='
        + $scope.selectedDepartureTime.departureTime,
        data: {}
    }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.otherDepartureTimes = result;
    });
}
```

Data is being submitted from a HTML form:

```
<label for="departAfter">Depart after:</label>
<select id="departAfter"
   ng-model="selectedDepartureTime"
   ng-options="time.departureTime for time in departureTimes"
   ng-init="selectedDepartureTime='undefined'">
</select>
```

To me, this seems like it should work - seems simple enough.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong with just the information you've posted. What's on line 80 and 85?

Comment: Line 80 and 85 are the console.log statements.

Comment: Where u have initialized $scope.selectedDepartureTime ?

Comment: Do you create the object before assign property to it?

Comment: @pac-man have added the form element where it comes from.

Comment: @raxell well, if no time is selected, I suppose it won't be initialised?

Comment: Instead of ng-init="selectedDepartureTime='undefined'" change to ng-init="selectedDepartureTime='{}'" or remove from there and initialize in controller

Comment: @pac-man that did it, thanks.

Comment: you try to do a `console.log($scope.selectedDepartureTime)` in line 80? Maybe is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `undefined` to `{}`.

```
<label for="departAfter">Depart after:</label>
<select id="departAfter"
   ng-model="selectedDepartureTime"
   ng-options="time.departureTime for time in departureTimes"
   ng-init="selectedDepartureTime={}"> <!-- Change undefined to {}-->
</select>
```